# Get specific array value

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var stored =
        [{subject:"farm",name:"John Doe"},
         {subject:"steam",name:"Michael Buck"},
         {subject:"finance",name:"Ron Ruckle"}, //need this
         {subject:"geo",name:"Ben Bond"}];
```

I need to get an specific array value. I know it is possible to do this:

```
     getitem = stored[2]["name"];
```

but since I don't know the row, only the first item's value I need something like this:

```
     getitem = stored["subject:finance"]["name"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to iterate and check:

```
function getNameFromSubject(subject) {
    for (var i = 0; i < stored.length; i++) {
        if (stored[i].subject == subject) return stored[i].name;
    }
    return null;
}

var name = getNameFromSubject("finance");
```

Comment: Okay. I already did that with: `for (var i=stored.length;i--;) {
        if (stored[i].subject == "finance") {
            return stored[i].name;
        }
    }` But I thought there would be an easier&cleaner solution. Thanks for answering. Will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

With modern browsers, you can use `filter()` to find the element you need, then get its name:

```
var results = stored.filter(
  function( item )
  {
    return item.subject == "finance";
  }
);

var name = results[0].name;
```

The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) show how to add a `filter()` method for older browsers, as well.